# Mono and ASP.NET Authentication

Tags: asp.net, authentication, mono

Does anyone know how to get to work the authentication mechanism configured using Web Site Administration Tool under Linux running Mono? Is it even possible?

Comment: Are you asking if it's possible to run the "Web Site Administration Tool" on Linux, or are you asking how to configure authentication on your ASP.Net application running on Linux?  Do you plan to use Forms authentication, or do you want to use something else?  If Forms authentication, then what kind of database will hold the users and roles - MS SqlServer, MySql, etc.?

Comment: I'd like to get Forms authentication, preferably using SQLite as the database but I'd very much like to use the WSAT to configure users and roles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you're going to find a ton of support for this, evidenced by the lack of activity on your question.  The Web Site Administration Tool was [removed from CodePlex around April 2009 due to inactivity](http://forums.asp.net/p/1390061/3415574.aspx) ([CodePlex rules](http://codeplex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CodePlex%20FAQ&referringTitle=CodePlex%20Help%20Wiki#Requirements) state: `It must be an ongoing project (no "abandoned" projects)`) and it's use/adoption really declined.  Many projects that were using it as a component just wrote their own after that.

There have been a few alternatives that have popped up in the community after it went missing:

- [Rolling Your Own Website Administration Tool](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020111539/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/052307-1.aspx)
- [Create Your Own Web Site Administration Tool in ASP.NET](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Web-Site-Administration-Tool.aspx)

I think using code from one of those two projects is going to come as close to what you're after as is available.  It's not ideal and will require some work to get working with the back-ends you desire (both of those use a SQL server back-end).  I know this answer sucks, but sometimes that's the answer.  I hope someone comes and proves me wrong and that what you want is out there, or at least could provide the WSAT source code as it last was on codeplex...that's be a huge head start in getting it to run.

*If you're referring to a different WSAT please comment and correct me....it's such a generic term really, but that was by far the most popular one so I based this answer on that.*

Comment: I'd like to know how the WSAT being removed from CodePlex impacts the fact that it is in fact part of the framework and/or VisualStudio. If you take a look how it's invoked then you'll clearly see that it's part of the tooling support.

Comment: Ah you are talking about something entirely different, do you want to run it from Linux or just point it to a linux/mono based site?

Comment: Ok so I was referring to the one that's most popular when you do a google search :) It's on most of the preliminary results when you search for it. So what I wanted to have is the same functionality available on Mono/Linux. I guess (judging from the other answer by Iain) it's probably going to have to end with a custom WSAT-like implementation.

Comment: @Matthias Hryniszak: I agreed...sorry the answer sucks, but sometimes what you're after just isn't written yet, unfortunately this is one of those.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set up your database schema manually for Membership/Roles support if using Mono. That said, [following the FAQ answer](http://www.mono-project.com/Guide:_Porting_ASP.NET_Applications#Membership.2FRoles.2FProfile_provider_schema) (which I have found very handy in the past) alone may not be enough, I am not sure about the other dependancies for the Web Site Administration Tool itself (e.g. any .NET specific libraries it needs) but combined with an [appropriate membership provider configured in system.web](http://www.mono-project.com/Guide:_Porting_ASP.NET_Applications#Membership.2FRoles_provider_configuration) I'd say there is a reasonable chance it may.

If that doesn't work for you, I would second Nick's suggestion of taking a look at the solution by 4GuysFromRolla.com who have a lot of good info relevant to both .NET & Mono.